# Finishing NSOperation on different thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation

I'm curious whether it is safe to finish custom NSOperation on different thread that their origin thread e.g.:

I have my custom operation class which is executed on different thread let say thread B (not main thread), then in this operation class I have obviously `start()` method, where on very beginning I'm invoking `[self markAsExecuting];` method to indicate that operation already starts their work and of course after some stuff I have to invoke `[self markAsFinished];` to indicate that all work has been done and operation is finished.
My question is: whether it is safe to invoke `[self markAsFinished];` method on different thread that my operation itself is execute let say thread C?

Some snipped code:

```
      - (void)start {
        @autoreleasepool {
// *** Thread B
            [self markAsExecuting];

            [apiManager fetchData completion:^(NSDictionary *data, NSError *error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                      // As we know in this case when we do not indicate that AFNetworking response handle should be executed on different thread by default it will be executed on main thread, so that why I'm dispatching expensive work to the background 
                    self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.something.myapp.backgroundQueue", 0);
            dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{

                      // Some expensive work
// *** Thread C
                        [weakSelf markAsFinished];
                    });

                } else {
// *** Main Thread
                    [weakSelf markAsFinished];
                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

I'm hope that my problem explanation was clear enough.

Comment: Just to be clear, why is there 3 threads in your code snippet ? You want to call `markAsFinished` in your main thread or in another background thread ?

Comment: I have created my own queue for this operation then in this operation I'm performing AFNetworking request where by default callback comes to main threat and this is why I use dispatch_async in AFNetworking response block. I want to invoke markAsFinished in  dispatch_async, so in different threat than operation itself. 

I already improve my sniped code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was maybe not precisely enough, `markAsFinish` method only set the Operation state to .finish so it doesn't make big different from which thread it is called in this case